# Cannot read property 'appendChild' of null JS img not uploading in my site

Tags: javascript, html, dom

i am trying to upload img to my site but js telling me that there are 404 error:
js:206 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'appendChild' of null

```
at HTMLButtonElement.onclick (Challenge 1.html:105)
```

html code

```
<div class="flex-blackjack-row-1">
            <div id="Your-box">
                <h2>You: <span id="your-blackjack-result">0</span></h2>
            </div>

            <div id="dealer-box">
                <h2>Dealer: <span id="dealer-blackjack-result">0</span></h2>
            </div>
          
        </div>
```

js code:

```
let blackjackGame = {
    'you': {'scoreSpan':'#your-blackjack-score', 'div':'#your-box', 'score': 0},
    'dealer': {'scoreSpan':'#dealer-blackjack-score', 'div':'#dealer-box', 'score': 0}
}

const YOU = blackjackGame['you']

function blackjackHit(){
   
    // ra yleoba xdebaaaaaa

    let cardImage = document.createElement('img');
    cardImage.src = 'https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/5/59/Playing_card_diamond_2.svg/1200px-Playing_card_diamond_2.svg.png'

    document.querySelector(YOU['div']).appendChild(cardImage)
   
    hitSound.play();
}
```

Comment: What is `YOU`??

Comment: ```let blackjackGame = {
    'you': {'scoreSpan':'#your-blackjack-score', 'div':'#your-box', 'score': 0},
    'dealer': {'scoreSpan':'#dealer-blackjack-score', 'div':'#dealer-box', 'score': 0}
}

const YOU = blackjackGame['you']```

Comment: Ok, so it looks like `YOU['div']` is `"#your-box'`. The `div` in your HTML has id `Your-box`. JavaScript is case sensitive.